# javascript regex does not work for sentence string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a function which takes string as an argument. Then if the string begins with capital letter then return true otherwise return false. But my current function only works for one word string which I want it to work for both one word and a whole sentence. How can I improve my code to achieve this? Secondly, it should not work when numbers are passed inside sentence. How can I do this?

Here is my code

```
function takeString (str) {
var regex = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;

if (str.match(regex)) {

   if (str.charAt(0) === str.toUpperCase().charAt(0)) {
      alert('true');
      return true;
   } else {
      alert('false');
      return false;
   }

} else {
    alert('Only letters please.');
}
}

takeString('This is'); // shows Only letters please which is wrong. this should work
takeString('String); // returns true which right
takeString('string'); // returns false which is right
takeString('This is 12312321'); // shows only letters please which is right bcoz it has digits
takeString('12312312'); // show Only letters please which is right.
```

​

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spaces aren't letters. You have to add them into your character set:

```
> 'This is a string'.match(/^[A-Za-z]+$/);
null
> 'This is a string'.match(/^[A-Za-z\s]+$/);
["This is a string"]
```

`\s` matches all whitespace, so if you don't want to match tabs, replace `\s` with a space.

Here's a slightly more condensed version of your code:

```
function takeString(str) {
    return str.match(/^[A-Z][A-Za-z ]*$/);
}
```

Comment: Or test the starting uppercase with the regex and eliminate the `toUpperCase()` stuff, a little something like this: `if (str.match(/^[A-Z][A-Za-z ]*$/))`...

Comment: @nnnnnn: Thanks, I'll add that in.

Comment: +1. You probably want `*` instead of `+` or it'll force a two-letter minimum.

Comment: `\s` also matches newlines and vertical tabs :)

Answer (score 0):

along with the regex advice given by Blender, you'll want to also do the following (in order to satisfy the need to check each word ... assuming words are space or tab separated only:

- use the split function to break the string into words ( var mywords = str.split(/\s+/) )
- iterate over mywords array returned by split, checking each array element against the regex
- return an error if the regex doesnt match
- return success if you match every word

  takeString (str) {

  var mywords = str.split(/\s+/);
    for (i = 0; i < mywords.length; i++) {
       if (str.match(/^[A-Z][A-Za-z]*$/) != true) {
           return false;
       }
     }
    return true;
  }

(someone needs to check my js ... )